# Twitter-oAuth-library for iPhone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, oauth, mgtwitterengine

I'm looking for a oAuth/xAuth-Twitter-library for iPhone/Objective-C. I found [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine), but that didn't work, as they don't even link to the external libraries needed for it to work (heck, the example you download doesn't even work out-of-the-box!).

So, do you know any alternative libraries that do this, or how I can make MGTwitterEngine work? Thank you.

Comment: If you fixed the example, why not send a patch back to the maintainer? This feedback loop is how open source code improves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you still use OAuth for Twitter? Twitter recommends to use [XAuth](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) as an alternative for Oauth in iPhone

If you really want to use OAuth, then I can suggest you [this library](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone). We used it before for OAuth, but now we changed to XAuth already

Comment: XAuth needs an approval from Twitter, doesn't it? Can you get that before the app is near the finish-line?

Comment: It takes us 1-2 days only to send and receive email from Twitter. For someone, it takes a couple of hours. You should try to ask for approval now, and then, after a day, if they don't answer anything, you may consider OAuth

Comment: "xAuth is still OAuth" -- the first sentence on the page you link to. :P

Answer (score 2):

There is now: http://github.com/tweetdeck/TDOAuth which TweetDeck use in their iPhone and iPad clients.

Answer (score 1):

A general OAuth library for iPhone that works with Twitter is [gtm-oauth](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/)

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation will be to use bengottlieb's file, it is an excellent option because it has Twitter+OAuth, so you have connection to the API and the methods to the desired authentication. it is a unification of several efforts into a simplificated library. Just to update a litle the answer.

Here is the gitHub link with the source code:

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone